# Fierz identity and its application

Tags: dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

I know there are very good explanations for Fierz identity in this platform. But I have a question about its application.

Consider a matrix element $M$ and we can write $M$ in the basis of 16 Dirac matrices ($1, \gamma_\mu,\gamma_\mu\gamma_5, \sigma_{\mu\nu}, \gamma_5$).

$$M=\sum_i c_i \Gamma_i Tr[M\Gamma_i]$$

where $\Gamma_i$ are Dirac matrices.

My question is what if I consider matrix element with combination of Dirac matrices or any four vector times Dirac matrices (for example consider $\epsilon_\mu \Gamma_i$). Am I free to write similar summation or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you adapt the normalisation coefficients $c_i$. Your basis should satisfy
$$ Tr[\Gamma^A \Gamma_B] = n \, \delta_{A,B}$$
where $n = \frac{1}{c_i} \forall i$

This was done in hep-ph/0412245 using a chiral basis, where $n=2$. In case of the basis you mentioned in the questions one has $n=4$.